# Unity can not Resolve the object and threw 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

Using Unity in a project (Unity 4.0.1)

When config Unity, I have

```
container.RegisterLeadDeliveryProvider<YardiPopcardProvider>(VendorTaskType.YardiPopcard);
```

Where RegisterLeadDeliveryProvider:

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterLeadDeliveryProvider<TProvider>(this IUnityContainer container, VendorTaskType type)
        where TProvider : ILeadDeliveryProvider<IBrandConfiguration>
{
    return container.RegisterType<ILeadDeliveryProvider<IBrandConfiguration>, TProvider>(type.ToString());
}
```

After this, I did

```
var type = VendorTaskType.YardiPopcard.ToString();
var isRegistered = container.IsRegistered<ILeadDeliveryProvider<IBrandConfiguration>>(type);
```

isRegustered == true. So, it registered the provider. But, if I use

```
var obj = container.Resolve<ILeadDeliveryProvider<IBrandConfiguration>>(type);
```

The obj is always null. Supposedly, it should be YardiPopcardProvider.

If debug it, it shows: obj threw an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'. The message is: Cannot load assembly 'D:\.......ScheduledTask.YardiPopcard.dll'. However, the dll file is there. Not sure how come it has this exception.

The solution structure is:

EXEConsole

YardiPopcardProvider

Unity
......

Unity project has the Unity Container, and register all objects. EXEConsole project get the Container, then resolve a ProviderTask object. In ProviderTask object, all it does is resolve the YardiPopcardProvider.

I can confirm that the ScheduledTask.YardiPopcard.dll is in EXEConsole and Unity folder.

Anyone knows how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Is the file path to the DLL the same as the hint path in the .csproj file for that reference? Do the assembly versions match? Is there perhaps a binding redirect in your app.config?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things that can cause this are :

- Your dll requires another dll which is missing.
- Your dll is x64 and the project is x86 or vice-versa.
- Your dll is marked as blocked due to being downloaded from the internet.
- Your dll is compiled for a different framework than the project.
- Your project is running as a user that does not have access to the dll.